# How to hide child component content in the parent when data binding in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am new in Angular,i have two components, the parent component is Tasks to load user tasks and the child is ActionsComponent to load actions of tasks, I want to pass accountId and taskId fields from the parent to the child, so I added the ActionsComponent and used data binding to fill those variables.

**Tasks:**

```
    export class Tasks implements OnInit {

    accountId: string = '';
    taskId!: string;
....
}
```

**Tasks HTML template:**

```
<app-actions [accountId]="accountId"  [taskId]="taskId" ></app-actions>

<h3>Your Tasks</h3>
<table id="mat-table" mat-table [dataSource]="accountsTasks" class="mat-elevation-z8">
....
</table>
```

And this is **app-actions** HTML template to show those fields:

```
<h3> stringValue value: {{ stringValue }}</h3>
<h3> accountId value: {{ accountId }}</h3>
```

**Tasks page:**
[image]

my problem is the entire content of the `app-actions` being displayed in the parent component page, i do not want to have child component content in the parent component, i want to just pass accountId and taskId fields to child and use them in child component, how can i do this without showing child component in the parent?
TNX

**Edit(Solution):**
*I used the route parameter to send the variable from the Task component to the Action component. i approved the solution.*

Comment: Why do you need a component that won't be visible? e.g. why are you using app-actions if the component itself won't do anything?

Comment: app-actions is supposed to load the related actions belonging to the current task from the tasks component in the ActionsComponent, I want to have task data and account data in the actions component to be able to load related actions in the actions template by calling another rest api

Comment: @mi_mo, Angular follows a MVC architecture: the components are the View part, and should only be responsible for showing things on the screen. The task you describe would belong to a Controller in MVC, so a Service in Angular. You can create and provide subservices that do what you want. Services are the "invisible components" that you are looking for.

Comment: @RobinDeSchepper Thanks for the explanation, i got what you said,i edited a question and added a Tasks picture, as you can see there I want the user can click on the Action button of each task then the Actions component will open in another route:".../actions" and the related actions to this specific task should there in app-actions, so for this purpose, i need to have a task id from Tasks component, so if i want to create a service for that(like what you said), how should i pass the task id from table in Tasks component to to Actions component and then load the related actions by a service?

Comment: I'll write a little answer, but I still barely understand what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understood you want to separate the loading logic, for the tasks in separate component called `app-actions` that should not be rendered in the `app-tasks`.

This is not possible with a component, as per definition components have a template that will be rendered.

In order to achieve the behavior of splitting the loading logic I would suggest two different approaches.

1. Create a service that will handle the loading logic and use it directly in the parent `app-tasks`.
2. Create a directive and handle the loading logic in the directive, as directives are pretty much a component without template, so you won't see any html rendered in the parent component.

Post edit:

3. Attach the component to a separate route and you can use the route parameters. So you will have a path

```
/actions/:accountId/:taskId
```

after that, you can get the ID from the router.

4. Pass the id-s through a shared service, then access the id-s from that shared service

Side note: I will go for option 3 if I'm in your shoes.

Comment: i edited a question and added a Tasks picture, as you can see there I want to user can click on the Action button of each task then the Actions component will open in another route:".../actions"  and the related actions to this specific task should there in app-actions, so for this purpose, i need to have a task id, so if i want to create a service for that(like what you said), how should i pass the task id from table in Tasks component to to Actions component and then load the related actions by a service? Thanks

Comment: @mi_mo did my "Post edit" suggestion handle the use-case that you have?

Comment: Thanks my friend, i used the route parameters to fulfill the need.

Answer (score 0):

Use behaviour subject concept in this case:-

Step 1:
Make service file. Example shown below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {  BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class <YourServiceName>{
  private subjects = new BehaviorSubject('');
  getDetails = this.subjects.asObservable();
    sendData(data1: any, data2: any) {
      let body: any = {
        data1: data1,
        data2: data2,
      }
      this.subjects.next(body);
    }
    }
  constructor() { }
}
```

Step 2:
Register service file in contructor of app-actions component. Then use sendData() function of service file to send both data as follows:

```
this.<YourServiceName>.sendData(accountId, taskId);
```

Step 3: Register service file in contructor of Tasks component and add below function in ngOnInit():

```
subscription : any;   //initialize in ts file
ngOnInit() {
this.subscription = this.<yourServicename>.getDetails.subscribe((res: any) => {
      if(res) {
        //here you will be receiving accountId and taskId from app-action component into Tasks component without rendering UI on HTML .
        }
})
}
```